# curl failed to connect

Tags: php, curl

I try to get data with curl from a piwik installation on the same server. I get this this error.

> Failed to connect to example.com port 80: Connection refused

This how my curl looks like:

```
    $url = 'http://example.com/index.php?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.getVisits&idSite=1&
nb_uniq_visitors&period=month&date=today&token_auth=blabla';

    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 30; // set to zero for no timeout
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $file_contents = curl_exec($ch);

    print_r (curl_error($ch));
    curl_close($ch);



    // display file
    print_r ($file_contents);
```

Does someone know how to fix this?
I turned off iptables.

Comment: What happens when you try to access the URL using a browser?

Comment: <result>11111</result>, it works if I visit the url directly

Comment: Great! The webserver is working, the URL is correct. No try to run `curl` as a command line on the same server where you run your PHP code: `$ curl 'http://example.com/index.php?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.getVisits&idSite=1&
nb_uniq_visitors&period=month&date=today&token_auth=blabla'`. Don't forget to put the URL in apostrophes in the command line. It is very important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.** check if your `allow_url_fopen` is enabled:

```
echo ini_get('allow_url_fopen');

ini_set('allow_url_fopen', 1);
```

**2.** if you have shell access to your server, open the URL with a local command (wget, w3m, lynx, curl command, telnet, ...):

```
wget http://www.example.com
telnet www.example.com 80
```

**3.** try to open a connection with another PHP function:

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if (!$fp) {
  echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
} else {
  $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
  $out .= "Host: www.example.com\r\n";
  $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
  fwrite($fp, $out);
  while (!feof($fp)) {
    echo fgets($fp, 128);
  }
  fclose($fp);
}
```

**4.** replace the host name by its IP:

```
$url = 'http://210.220.112.2/index.php?module=API&method=VisitsSummary.getVisits&idSite=1&
nb_uniq_visitors&period=month&date=today&token_auth=blabla';
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` instructs `cUrl` to read the received headers and if the status code is `301` or `302` (redirect) and the `Location:` header is found then it should issue a new request to the provided location. But the OP says the error is `cannot connect`. There is no response received.